# Calculating vega in Heston?

Tags: hedging, heston, vega

I often see Vega in the Heston model specified as:
\begin{align*}
    \nu & = 
    \frac{\partial C}{\partial v} =
    \frac{\partial C}{\partial v_0} 2 \sqrt{v_0}
\end{align*}
where $v = \sqrt{v_0}$.

Why are we setting $v = \sqrt{v_0}$?

Where is the square-root and "$2$" coming from?

Comment: Let $V$ denote the variance and $v$ the volatility, i.e. $V=v^2$. The natural argument for stochastic volatility models is typically the variance. However, using the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), we can compute vega in terms of the volatility: $$\frac{\partial C}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial C}{\partial V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial C}{\partial V}\frac{\partial v^2}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial C}{\partial V}2v=\frac{\partial C}{\partial V}2\sqrt{V}.$$ Writing $V_0$ and $v_0=\sqrt{V_0}$ emphasises that we talk about the _spot_ variance and volatility.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you! I would market your question as the answer if I could:-).

Comment: I added the comment as an answer:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V$ denote the variance and $v$ the volatility, i.e. $V=v^2$. The natural argument for the option price under a stochastic volatility model is typically the variance, i.e. $C_\text{SV}=C_\text{SV}(S_0,V_0,...)$. However, using the chain rule, we can compute vega in terms of the volatility: $$\nu=\frac{\partial C_\text{SV}}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial C_\text{SV}}{\partial V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial C_\text{SV}}{\partial V}\frac{\partial v^2}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial C_\text{SV}}{\partial V}2v=\frac{\partial C_\text{SV}}{\partial V}2\sqrt{V}.$$ We do this in order to resemble the Black-Scholes vega which is the partial derivative of the Black-Scholes option price, $C_\text{BS}=C_\text{BS}(S_0,\sigma,...)$, with respect to $\sigma$. Of course, when we have $\frac{\partial C_\text{BS}}{\partial \sigma}$, we can easily infer $\frac{\partial C_\text{BS}}{\partial \sigma^2}$ using again the chain rule. This would be the Black-Scholes vega with respect to the variance.

The model-free put-call parity implies that European-style put and call options have the same vega (with respect to volatility or variance).

Writing $V_0$ and $v_0=\sqrt{V_0}$ emphasises that we talk about the *spot* variance and volatility.

Comment: Nice and clean. Just to make sure: The Heston Vega is computed using the Heston call price function $C(S_0,v_0,\ldots)$ (obviously).

Comment: @Kermittfrog Fair point. I added the point in case it caused any confusion for anyone. Thanks!